# How to make python functions bind enclosing variable to value rather than to name

Tags: python, closures, python-decorators, scoping

In python functions its perfectly legal to reference variables from enclosing scopes. These variables refer to whatever value they posses at the time the function is called. So, for instance

```py
x = 1 # unused
def foo(y):
    return x+y

x=10
print(foo(1)) # prints 11
x=11
print(foo(1)) # prints 12
```

is it possible to make the variable `x` be frozen to whatever the value of `x` was at creation time? That is, I want the `x` in `foo` to bind to the value of the outer `x` rather than its name. Basically the behavior I want is

```py
x = 1
def foo(y):
    return 1+y # I'd rather not hard code the value of x here

x=10
print(foo(1)) # prints 2
x=11
print(foo(1)) # prints 2
```

I currently have a working solution, but It's not very readable, I think there might be a better solution (a decorator perhaps?)

my solution

```py
x = 1
def wrapper():
    local_x = x
    def foo(y):
        return local_x+y
    return foo
foo = wrapper()

x=10
print(foo(1)) # prints 2
x=11
print(foo(1)) # prints 2
```

Comment: Why not make x an argument to wrapper? What you are creating is basically a decorator. You may want to also look at functools.partial.

Comment: @PaulRooney I'm not sure what you mean. how would passing x as an argument to wrapper help here? unless you meant passing x to foo, which I don't want to do every time the function gets called. This isn't exactly a decorator since wrapper isn't taking the function foo as an argument. I thought about using functools.partial to redifine the function too, but that's also not very readable and is less powerful than my posted solution.

Comment: No I'm not talking about passing x to `foo`. It helps because it cuts reliance on global variables.Globals are generally a bad thing, there's a lot of info out there on that subject. If they work for you though then you should use them. As for partial being less readable and less powerful, I don't see it, but its a matter of opinion. What you have is ultimately a more limited version of partial.

Comment: @PaulRooney Sorry for the confusion, but I didn't mean its less readable than my solution, I just meant its not any more readable, but I guess that's debatable

Comment: Yes now I read it again, I see what you were saying. My misunderstanding. partial doesn't buy you much (saves a five line function). Not sure you are likely to find something a whole lot better though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to apply the first argument and get a new function accepting one argument. I chose not to decorate the add function, as it is very general and useful elsewhere.

```
from functools import partial
from operator import add       # does same thing as your foo

x = 1
foo = partial(add, x)
print(foo(1)) # prints 2

x = 11

print(foo(1)) # prints 2
```

In keeping with your original solution, you could also do something like.

```
def wrapper(localx):
    def foo(y):
        return localx + y
    return foo

foo2 = wrapper(x)
print(foo2(1)) # prints 12
```

Note that now the dependency on a global is cut and you could even pass a literal value to `wrapper` (e.g. `foo3 = wrapper(5)`).

Answer (score 3):

You can also take advantage of a default argument:

```
x = 1
def foo(y, x=x):
    return x + y

x=10
print(foo(1)) # prints 2
x=11
print(foo(1)) # prints 2
```

Comment: Holy crap, that is clever.

Comment: I completely forgot that default argument are bound during function creation. Good stuff.